Dacpac CI/CD deploy to Azure portal failing
Azure Dacpac publish via CI/CD to Azure cloud DB failing with below error, it succeeded for one database but failing for other database.
Initializing deployment (Start)

*** A project which specifies SQL Server 2019 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Initializing deployment (Failed)

Time elapsed 0:38:16.05
##[error]*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
##[error]Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2019 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
##[error]Failed to import target model [DBName]. Detailed message Unable to reconnect to database: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
##[error]Operation cancelled by user.
##[error]Unable to reconnect to database: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
##[error]Operation cancelled by user.
##[error]Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
##[error]Operation cancelled by user.
##[error]The wait operation timed out
##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-


Does it work if you deploy from your local machine, such as using Visual Studio? What is the target platform of another DB project that can be deployed successfully?

from visual studio deployment working. Other successful db target type is azure sql ,s1 subscription.

Try to change the target platform of the failed DB project to be same as that of the successful DB project, then check if it can work. @Swaroop

I am using build pipeline to fist publish to Dev db, and then to Val DB, Dev is succeeding, whereas val fails. I am using below variable for deployment: /P:ALLOWINCOMPATIBLEPLATFORM=True

The "Dev db" and "Val DB" are two Azure SQL Database created on Azure Portal, right? And you try to deploy the same database project to them, but one is successful while another is failed.

yes correct, dev is successfull, whereas val db failing.

Try to change the Target platform of the database project to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database". See my answer below for more details.

I can reproduce the similar issue if setting the Target platform of the database project to "SQL Server 2019". In the project file (.sqlproj), the corresponding value of DSP is "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider".

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    . . .
  </PropertyGroup>
  . . .
</Project>


##[error]A project which specifies SQL Server 2019 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.



After changing the Target platform to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database" on the database project, re-build it to generate a new .dacpac file, and then the deployment task can work fine to deploy the .dacpac file.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    . . .
  </PropertyGroup>
  . . .
</Project>




Have you tried to change the Target platform to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database" on your database project? Does it work for you? @Swaroop
